# Remove \(backslash) with "" in database field using update command in SQL

Tags: mysql

When I run this sql command:

```
UPDATE chat_data 
SET message = replace(message, '\', '') 
LIMIT 1 ;
```

It gives me syntax error:

> 13:07:46 UPDATE chat_data SET message = replace(message, '\', '')
>   LIMIT 1 ; Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near ''\', '') LIMIT 1' at line 1 0.237 sec

**Any solution for this ?**

Comment: What is the error? Post it please

Comment: 13:07:46 UPDATE chat_data SET message = replace(message, '\', '') LIMIT 1 ; Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\', '') LIMIT 1' at line 1 0.237 sec

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape the `\` character:

```
UPDATE chat_data SET message = replace(message, '\\', '') LIMIT 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a case today on a legacy project.
Here is a solution for a SELECT statement :

```
'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE label = REPLACE("'.mysql_real_escape_string($label).'", "'.mysql_real_escape_string('\\').'", "")'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace visible backslash (\) with sql you could also use
`REPLACE(message, CHAR(92), '')`